# wp7 error handling

Tags: error-handling, windows-phone-7

I have an ErrorPage.xaml page in my WP7 application.  When an unhandled exception occurs, the method in app.xaml.cs is called and that passes the exception to the ErrorPage.xaml.cs and the error is displayed to the user with a link to go back to the main page.
If I click on the AppBar IconButton too fast, then the Navigation Failed event is raised, errorpage is still called but nothing is displayed on the error page. The AppBar is the only thing visible.

Cannot figure out why

Here is the code in my app.xaml.cs

```
        // Code to execute on Unhandled Exceptions
    private void Application_UnhandledException(object sender, ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            // An unhandled exception has occurred; break into the debugger
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
        }

        e.Handled = true;
        ErrorPage.Exception = e.ExceptionObject;
        (RootVisual as Microsoft.Phone.Controls.PhoneApplicationFrame).Source =
            new Uri(Navigation.PAGE_ERROR, UriKind.Relative);
    }
```

**Error.xaml is like this**

```
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{StaticResource GlobalPageBackgroundBrush}" CacheMode="BitmapCache">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="24,24,0,12">
        <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle" Text="{StaticResource AppName}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle" Text="error" Margin="-3,-8,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1">
        <TextBlock x:Name="ErrorText" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle3Style}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
        <StackPanel x:Name="FriendlyErrorStackPanel" Margin="0,100,0,0" Orientation="Vertical">
            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle3Style}" TextWrapping="Wrap">
                <TextBlock.Text>
                   Please click the link below to return to the main page of the application.
                </TextBlock.Text>
            </TextBlock>                
            <HyperlinkButton Style="{StaticResource PhoneHyperlinkStyle}" Content="Start Over" NavigateUri="/Views/MainPage.xaml" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

and finally the ErrorPage.xaml.cs is

```
    public partial class ErrorPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public ErrorPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static Exception Exception;

    // Executes when the user navigates to this page.
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Exception != null)
        {
            if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
            {
                FriendlyErrorStackPanel.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
                ErrorText.Text = Exception.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                FriendlyErrorStackPanel.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
                ErrorText.Text = GlobalConstants.DEFAULT_ERROR_MESSAGE;
            }
        }

        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: my concern would be that you are navigating **forward** from this error page back to main.  that implies that you could press _back_ 2x, and presumably get back to the error condition?

Comment: WP7 training toolkit shows a sample where an error page is shown to the user for unhandled exception. I extended it to display a friendly message to the user so they can go to the main page and start using the app again. Do you see any problems with this passing certification?

Comment: @PratikKothari I've got multiple apps in the marketplace where you can head back from the error page to try the previous action again, so it definitely passes certification. With Mango/ WP 7.1, you could also clear the backstack so that pressing back exits your app, but its up to you to decide whether you want people to be able to try again, or if you can detect when an error is critical and they need to restart the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect once it hits Application_UnhandledException and the Exception is set as Handled = true, it might get flaky if you get two in rapid succession - the way around this would be to make sure that the AppBar Button allows only one press while its trying to do something (so disable while its trying to navigate, and re-enable if it fails)

Also, consider using Dispatcher.BeginInvoke() for your Navigate method call if you aren't already doing so.